# Python won't run everytime i try to run it, why is this?

Tags: python, python-idle

Firstly, sorry i'm just a beginner. Everytime i try to run/open python an IDLE subprocess error message comes up saying 'socket error: conection refused'. I'm not sure what to do about it, and because of this i can't use python. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Exactly what do you do/type/click in order to get this message? Which platform are you on?

Comment: I just click on a python IDLE shorcut i have created in my start menu. I'm using windows 7. 
Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you have to create a firewall rule for IDLE, since it uses a network connection for certain tasks. Unfortunately I could not find any documentation on this topic, but I think it can be read in the IDLE README.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got some kind of firewall in place that prevents IDLE from opening a local network connection. What kind of firewall are you using?

PS - in a pinch, you can just run python.exe from where it is installed and use a standard text editor (such as Notepad++) to create new scripts and modules. Do you know how to set the PATH environment variable in Windows? Where did you install Python?

Comment: Much Thanks.
I'm using 'ESET smart security''s firewall, as i've found ESET is very good for virus'. Do you know how i could create a firewall rule for python IDLE?
No i don't know about the path enviroment variable, how do i do it?
I just intsalled it into the local disk.